# How to proper set aria-labels on Select component with dropdown options

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm trying to set aria-labels and accessibility settings on Select dropdown

I have a Select component that maps through options. Kinda confused on how to set aria-labels and connect them in a proper way. Do they need to point to each other? Like The dropdown itself with the alternatives?

```
<StyledSelect
        key={JSON.stringify(eventTypes)}
        data-attr="eventType"
        error={item.errors && item.errors.noEvent && item.errors.noEvent[0]}
        onChange={e => onChange(e, item)}
        placeholder={intl.formatMessage(generalMessages.incident)}
        value={`${item.updates.eventType || ''}`}
        formatValue={val => eventTypes.find(type => type.id === val)
        && i18nFormat.membersEventTypes
          .getNameForType(intl, eventTypes.find(type => type.id === val))}
        variant="round"
      >
        {eventTypes
          .map(type => (
            <Option key={`${type.name}_${type.id}`} value={`${type.id}`}>{i18nFormat.membersEventTypes.getNameForType(intl, type)}</Option>
            // <Divider key=sch{`${key}_divider`} />
          ))}
      </StyledSelect>
```

So I need aria-labels inside the  component there, but do I need to point/referrer to the parent?

Comment: Hi stamy, I'm not sure to understand what you are exactly trying to achieve. Your markup seems quite explicit, what do you need `aria-label`s for?

Comment: @dashdashzako WCAG requirements. But I assume I have to set it in the Select since Option has values and the screenreader will read the Select and then refer to the value in option?

Answer (score 8):

To clear things a little bit, assistive technology requires your `select` to be labelled. But if there are multiple ways to achieve this, you should **only use one of them**.

Using more doesn't make your DOM invalid in the sense that it won't break your application, but it's a bit like trying to steer a wheel in both directions at once, and I'm not sure how screen readers handle that.

The first way to achieve this is to simply use a `label` element.
I personally like this one because it has the benefit of making the `select` purpose easy to identify for sighted users, and lets you use a combination of icon and text if you want.

```
<label htmlFor="my-select">Colors</label>
<SelectComponent id="my-select" value="red">
  <option key="color_red">Red</option>
  <option key="color_green">Green</option>
  <option key="color_blue">Blue</option>
  <option key="color_yellow">Yellow</option>
</SelectComponent>
```

Variant with `select` inside `label`:

```
<label>
  Colors
  <SelectComponent value="red">
    <option key="color_red">Red</option>
    <option key="color_green">Green</option>
    <option key="color_blue">Blue</option>
    <option key="color_yellow">Yellow</option>
  </SelectComponent>
</label>
```

VoiceOver on Safari will read it like this:

[image: VoiceOver reading the above code: "red, Colors, pop up button"]

If you don't want to use an extraneous element, you can simply use the `aria-label` attribute. Note that it may be difficult to know what the `select` refers to if there is no context nearby.

```
<SelectComponent aria-label="Basic colors" value="red">
  <option key="color_red">Red</option>
  <option key="color_green">Green</option>
  <option key="color_blue">Blue</option>
  <option key="color_yellow">Yellow</option>
</SelectComponent>
```

[image: VoiceOver reading the above code: "red, Basic colors, pop up button"]

Finally, you can refer to an element as the label.

```
<span id="my-element">Colors</span>
<SelectComponent aria-labelledby="my-element">
  <option key="color_red">Red</option>
  <option key="color_green">Green</option>
  <option key="color_blue">Blue</option>
  <option key="color_yellow">Yellow</option>
</SelectComponent>
```

Though this is convenient if you already have a relevant element somewhere in your DOM and you don't want to create an extraneous element, I wouldn't use it for form elements.

Form labels have expected behaviours (focus related element when clicked for example) that you will need to reimplement on the element, which is a tedious task.

I tend to use this mostly when I have a `div role="region"` that has a meaningful header inside of it.